# Tinymce Form submit field collision

Tags: plugins, tinymce, save, wysiwyg

I am using TinyMCE in my project. Save plugin is very good. Because you do not have to press the submit button located bottom of the page. But I'm getting **"Error: Form submit field collision"** error when I use save plugin. I tried `$("#form").bind("form-pre-serialize", function() { tinymce.triggerSave(); });` but did not work. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent two hours on searching what was wrong with it! The problem was with the submit button "name" attribute - when you set it to "submit" it makes the plugin check on collisions fail resulting in the error. Renaming the button resolves the issue.